# How to display JSON data from a rails API to ember.js view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js

I have a rails API that when I load a particular route it returns a JSON response to my browser.  The URL I put in my browser is http://localhost:3000/api/csv_files

And the output looks like the following,
[image: API output]

Now I want to load this output / `csv_files` using ember.js but I am not entirely sure how this would work?

I included `ember-rails` gem in my rails app, and I have the appropriate files loaded in the rails app, but I am not sure how I could connect an ember template to the rails API controller to display the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [route](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/) to load your data.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
 model() {
    return Ember.$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/csv_files' })
 }
 });
```

And then in your template you can

```
{{#each model as |csv|}}
  {{csv.id}} - {{csv.csv_file_name}}
{{/each}}
```

You may want to define [Models](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/) that represent you data, so that you can use a solution such as Ember Data.